# How to run $pull and $set at the same time in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to run the below query.

```
db.collection.update_many(
        {"id":{"$in":id_list}},
        {"$set":
            {
                "update": {'rank':'abc'}
            }
        },
        {
            { "$pull": { "email": 'test@test.com' } }
        }

    )
```

When I run this , I am getting below error.

```
upsert should be true or false
```

On doing some research, found that we can't use two updates at the same time. So as a workaround I am running each update individually and it works fine.

First this,

```
db.collection.update_many(
        {"id":{"$in":id_list}},
        {"$set":
            {
                "update": {'rank':'abc'}
            }
        }

    )
```

and then,

```
db.collection.update_many(
        {"id":{"$in":id_list}},
        {
            { "$pull": { "email": 'test@test.com' } }
        }

    )
```

Is this a good approach ? Is there a better solution for this issue where I do not have to make 2 calls to the db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update argument should be a single object, with fields named like `$set`, and `$pull`.  If you combined those into a single object passed as the second argument, it should work, like:

```
db.collection.update_many(
        {"id":{"$in":id_list}},
        {
         "$set": {"update": {'rank':'abc'} },
         "$pull": { "email": 'test@test.com' }
        }
    )
```